# How can I add my script to admin using script-loader.php?

Tags: wp-admin, scripts, core-modifications

I'm trying to load my custom script in the admin panel using the same method that WordPress itself loads scripts in the admin area.

This is an example script being loaded by `wp-includes/script-loader.php`:

```
$scripts->add(
    'password-strength-meter',
    "/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter$suffix.js",
    array( 'jquery', 'zxcvbn-async' ), 
    false, 
    1
);
```

So I tried to add my own script by the same method. I :

- Created a file named `user-profile-validator.js` inside `/wp-admin/js/` (also created a minified version)
- Tried to enqueue it by using the following code:

---

```
$scripts->add(
    'user-profile-validator',
    "/wp-admin/js/user-profile-validator$suffix.js",
    array( 'jquery' ), 
    false, 
    1
);
```

But nothing happened, it's neither added to URL, nor I can find my script amongst loaded scripts.

Why is this happening?

**PS:** I'm doing a patch, that is why I'm modifying the core files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'e are only *registering* it with:

```
$scripts->add( 'user-profile-validator', ...)
```

but not *enqueueing* it.

Check e.g. how  [`wp_register_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) is a wrapper for the `WP_Scripts::add()` method.

Additionally add:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'user-profile-validator' );
```

in the relevant admin file to enqueue it or add it as a *dependency* for another enqueued script.

Note that `password-strength-meter` is a dependency for  the `user-profile` script:

```
$scripts->add( 
    'user-profile', 
    "/wp-admin/js/user-profile$suffix.js", 
    array( 'jquery', 'password-strength-meter', 'wp-util' ), 
   false, 
   1 
);
```

that's enqueued with :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'user-profile' );
```

in the backend.

Comment: Thanks! The moment I saw the +5 rep I knew you're gonna post an answer :P And yes, I noticed that I had to enqueue it too in the `user.php`, overlooked.

Comment: I found it interesting question ;-) ... and also interesting to see that core isn't using `wp_register_script()`. @JackJohansson

Comment: Seems like one of those spooky global variables to me. However, the handler `->add()` can be misleading. It seems like it's adding the script to the loaded, but it's just registering. `->register()` could be less confusing.

Comment: yes, I don't know why `add()` was used instead of `register()`, but  I guess it orginially referred to "adding" to the queue? It comes now from `WP_Dependencies::add()`.